# How to include files and folders in the deployment of a visual studio, C# project?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, deployment

I am working on a C# application.  Inside this program it looks through a directory and uses files in the same directory containing the exe files in the debug folder.  I added a setup project, for deployment, to the solution for the application.  I tend to be naive and figured I could just drop the files and folders into the installation folder after I install it on another computer.  I know there is a way to add these files and folders to the projects and set it up to have the installer install these files at the time of installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are working with Visual Studio 2010, and using Visual Studio Installer `Setup Project` to create an MSI output file.

Right click on the Setup project, select `View` menu, and select `File System`.
In there you are able to define files and folders to be installed.