# Where should I put the python files called by my application?

Tags: python, c#, file, release

I'm creating a C# windows form application (with visual studio), which calls some already created python files sometimes. I would like to know where should I put them. Because once I create a Release of my application, I've got the .exe etc. in my bin/Release folder and this is what I share to people who wants to use my application. But of course actually it doesn't work because they don't have my python files.

As I'm a beginner, I'd like to know where should I put those python file to make a clean application? In a new folder into my bin/Release folder so they are always here in the release or elsewhere?

I'd like to learn how to create something professional, thanks!

Comment: Most code editors, such as Visual Studio, have a built-in publisher for creating a release version of an app. For example, see this tutorial talking about how to publish a Console App from VS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include files and folders in the deployment of a visual studio, C# project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301604/how-to-include-files-and-folders-in-the-deployment-of-a-visual-studio-c-sharp-p) or [Including folder in setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108840/include-folder-in-setup-project)